# Python 3.5 - Creating Named Tuple Populated With Generators

Tags: python, iterator, generator, list-comprehension, namedtuple

Trying to compact my code and am very new to Python so I apologize if there is a previous topic covering exactly what I want.  I've tried searching and reading a lot with little success.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

(Please assume the cell calls are from some random spreadsheet with the data I need in the order presented.)

```
import xlrd
import collections

L_col = (21, 0, 27, 24, 3, 4, 11, 35, 18, 26)
L_label = ('Room_ID', 'Name', 'Type', 'Area', 'Sens_Cooling', 'Lat_Cooling', 'Heating', 'Ventilation', 'People', 'Volume')
sp = collections.namedtuple('Space', ['Room_ID', 'Name', 'Type', 'Area', 'Sens_Cooling', 'Lat_Cooling', 'Heating',
                                      'Ventilation', 'People', 'Volume'])

a = (L_ws.cell_value(row, L_col[0]) for row in range(start, end))
b = (L_ws.cell_value(row, L_col[1]) for row in range(start, end))
c = (L_ws.cell_value(row, L_col[2]) for row in range(start, end))
d = (L_ws.cell_value(row, L_col[3]) for row in range(start, end))
e = (L_ws.cell_value(row, L_col[4]) for row in range(start, end))
f = (L_ws.cell_value(row, L_col[5]) for row in range(start, end))
g = (L_ws.cell_value(row, L_col[6]) for row in range(start, end))
h = (L_ws.cell_value(row, L_col[7]) for row in range(start, end))
i = (L_ws.cell_value(row, L_col[8]) for row in range(start, end))
j = (L_ws.cell_value(row, L_col[9]) for row in range(start, end))

rs = sp(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do following:

```
import xlrd
import collections

def create_gen(column, start, end):
    return (L_ws.cell_value(row, column) for row in range(start, end))

L_col = (21, 0, 27, 24, 3, 4, 11, 35, 18, 26)
L_label = ('Room_ID', 'Name', 'Type', 'Area', 'Sens_Cooling', 'Lat_Cooling', 'Heating', 'Ventilation', 'People', 'Volume')
sp = collections.namedtuple('Space', L_label)
rs = sp(*(create_gen(col, start, end) for col in L_col))
```

Since you already have the field names in `L_label` you can pass that to `namedtuple` instead of creating another list.

For generators you can write generator expression that iterates over column in `L_col`. For every column the generator expression calls a separate method that returns a generator just like one you created earlier. Note that you need to use [closure](https://eev.ee/blog/2011/04/24/gotcha-python-scoping-closures/) here since `col` is evaluated when generator is called. Finally the result is unpacked with `*` operator before passed to `sp`.

Comment: I am having the same problem with the above where each generator in rs is giving me the 'Volume' rather than the variable specified.  So,    'print(list(rs.Name))'    and     'print(list(rs.Area))'    both give the Volume rather than the Name or Area.

Comment: @njohnson: Great catch, I've changed my example to use closure which fixes the problem. For detailed explanation on what was going on see https://eev.ee/blog/2011/04/24/gotcha-python-scoping-closures/.

Comment: Totally works now, I'll read up and see if I can wrap my brain around what's going on, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you can do:

```
items = [
    [L_ws.cell_value(row, L_col[i]) for row in range(start, end)]
    for i in range(10)]
rs = sp(*items)
```

If you need to have a generator in your items, I'd advise using a generator function:

```
def gen_item(column_number):
    for row_number in range(start, end):
        yield L_ws.cell_value(row_number, L_col[column_number])

rs = sp(*(gen_item(i) for i in range(10)))
```

<sup>This generator assumes that `start`, `end` and `L_col` are picked up via closure.  If you'd rather, you can pass them as parameters.</sup>

Also, you have a bit of repetition above:

```
L_label = ('Room_ID', 'Name', 'Type', 'Area', 'Sens_Cooling', 'Lat_Cooling', 'Heating', 'Ventilation', 'People', 'Volume')
sp = collections.namedtuple('Space', ['Room_ID', 'Name', 'Type', 'Area', 'Sens_Cooling', 'Lat_Cooling', 'Heating',
                                      'Ventilation', 'People', 'Volume'])
```

can probably be just:

```
L_label = ('Room_ID', 'Name', 'Type', 'Area', 'Sens_Cooling', 'Lat_Cooling', 'Heating', 'Ventilation', 'People', 'Volume')
sp = collections.namedtuple('Space', L_label)
```

With that said ... It feels a little odd to be putting generator expressions into a named-tuple (though there's no really good reason why you *can't* either)...

Comment: Ok great thanks.  Yeah, well I'm going to have potentially hundreds of data points represented and I'd rather acess each value when needed rather than loading them all into memory is my reasoning.  There are a series of calculations that will need to be processed and I thought it would be more convenient?

Comment: For  whatever reason when I do a check by: 'print(list(rs.Name))' I am not getting the same results when the code is more explicit as before.

Comment: @njohnson -- snap.  That's because you are using generators and it'll pick up the value of `i` when called, not when defined.  In otherwords, all of your generators would be referencing the _last_ column.  personally, I'd just switch it to a list-comprehension (which is what I've done in the answer) since having a tuple of lists makes more sense to me than a tuple of generators.  But, I don't know why you used generators in the first place (and you might have a good reason for it)...

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to use generators so I don't have to hold lists in memory needlessly, and by using them to generate a list when necessary or grab values for calculations I'm hoping the garbage collection, etc. will keep things lean.  Right now I don't have a ton of data, but there eventually will be and if I'm using generators 'correctly' (which hopefully I am) this should make things faster in the long run.  But again, I'm new to python, generators, etc.  Was using MATLAB for years and am just fascinated by generators and comprehensions in Python :)

Comment: @njohnson -- Sure.  Generators are great.  Generator expressions are great.  Comprehensions are great :-).  In this case, if you do use a function, (as proposed in the accepted answer), I'd probably just write a generator function rather than a function that returns a generator.  Usage should be indistinguishable, but I think the generator function is slightly more clear.  I've added an example to my answer.